# use poedit to translate codeiginiter lang array

Tags: php, codeigniter, localization, translation, po

I have a codeigniter application which uses arrays to fetch the correct string for a given language. This is what the core codeigniter system does, so I assumed this was the correct way of doing things.

However, this does not allow for easy translation, As there will be many files and they will be troublesome to keep consistent if there are any changes in the strings.

I was thinking about writing a parser, to go through the _lang.php files and fetch all the strings into some kind of database or flat file (.po)
Are there any tools out there to help with this, or do I have to write my own parser?

I found one [online tool](https://localise.biz/free/converter) that can convert between php and .po files, but it renames my array indexes to the actual string to be translated.

e.g.

```
$lang['index_title'] = 'List of your items';
```

will be converted to

```
$lang['list_of_your_items'] = 'List of your items';
```

this can cause collisions where two target strings happen to be the same for now, but may change in the future. (e.g. `title = 'samestring', section1 = "samestring"`)

Is there another way to handle this translation process?

If I go with gettext calls instead, it would mean also converting the codeigniter core, which will make future upgrades difficult.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PoEdit and PHP annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563403/poedit-and-php-annotations)

Comment: Store everything in the database, the original language & the translations it would be easier.